# Zend Framework can't see forms folder

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my Zend Framework project I have the forms folder in which I have a form

```
class Application_Forms_Loginextends Zend_Form
{
public function init() {
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');
    $username->setLabel('Username')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
    $password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
    $password->setLabel('password:')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
    $signin = $this->createElement('submit', 'signin');
    $signin->setLabel("sign in")->setIgnore(true);
    $this->addElements(array(
        $username, $password, $signin
    ));
}
```

}

I use this class in a UserController, but this error appears

```
Fatal error: Class 'LoginForm' not found in
```

edit:

```
 public function loginAction() {
    $users = new Application_Model_Users();
    $form = new Application_Forms_Login();
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Now I am getting this error

```
Warning: include_once(Application/Forms/Login.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myFolder/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

edit: added project structure

[image: project structure]

Comment: Show your controller code where you creating your form object.

Comment: you are using it wrong, see my answer, hope it clarifies it.

Comment: Please show your config.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error says it all
you said you have `form`s folders but you are using class of `LoginForm`

assuming you are using zf1,

and your forms folder is under application,

you should use it like this,

```
class Application_Forms_LoginFrom extends Zend_Form
```

it can very according to your folders name.

also change the call in controller as

```
  $form = new Application_Forms_LoginForm();
```

it should be as per your folder name whether you use `Application_form` or `Application_Forms`.

ah i see,
now you are using ,

```
class Application_Forms_Loginextends Zend_Form
```

may be there is typo and you forgot the space between login and extends,

try this,

```
 class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
```

Comment: I did this, but now i get this error    Warning: include_once(Application/Forms/LoginForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/alexandru.luca/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php

Comment: do you have directory named Forms ?? or Form ? under application directory

Comment: forms... It works now but I get a different error now, I updated the post

Comment: I user Application_Forms_Login extends Zend_Form and I call it like $form = new Application_Forms_Login); The problem is this Warning: include_once(Application/Forms/Login.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myFolder/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php

Comment: Yes, it throws this error: Warning: include_once(Application/Forms/Login.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myFolder/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php

Comment: yes, remove the s from Application_Forms, and try Application_Form

Answer (score 0):

class Application_Forms_Loginextends Zend_Form it should be class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form

Comment: can you please be more specific? i'm new to Zend

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
public function init() {
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');
    $username->setLabel('Username')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
    $password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
    $password->setLabel('password:')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
    $signin = $this->createElement('submit', 'signin');
    $signin->setLabel("sign in")->setIgnore(true);
    $this->addElements(array(
        $username, $password, $signin
    ));
}
```

and in your controller action :

```
$form = new Application_Form_Login();
```

If error persist check your application.ini for appnamespace = "Application"

Answer (score 0):

In Zend Framework, the default `appnamespace` config value is `Application`.

Name your class `Application_Form_Login` instead of `Application_Forms_Login` and it will work with no issue.

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init() {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');
        $username->setLabel('Username')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
        $password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
        $password->setLabel('password:')->setAttrib('maxLength', 75);
        $signin = $this->createElement('submit', 'signin');
        $signin->setLabel("sign in")->setIgnore(true);
        $this->addElements(array(
            $username, $password, $signin
        ));
}
```

Hope it helps